# How can I create a log file using a tcl script

Tags: tcl

If I want to create a logfile from a Tcl script ..is there any command in Tcl to do so and what are packages required for it ?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Did you try anything ? How a standard output is not enough ? This is unclear...

Comment: I dont even know what to write in a tcl script to create a log-file ...can u give any example

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`logger`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/log/logger.html) package in Tcllib. If you've used logging systems in other languages, it should feel fairly familiar:

```
package require logger
set log [logger::init myservice]

${log}::notice "Initialized myservice logging"
# ... code ...
${log}::notice "Ending myservice logging"

${log}::delete
```

By default, it logs to the console. To log to a file, you need a little extra code, perhaps like this:

```
set logfile [open "myfile.log" "a"];   #### <<<< Open in APPEND mode!
proc logtofile {msg} {
    global logfile
    puts $logfile "[clock format [clock seconds]]: NOTICE: $msg"
}
${log}::logproc notice logtofile
```

Of course, you could also cut out the middle-man and just use that `logtofile` procedure directly…